# Applescript to time daily usage

Tags: applescript

I am trying to make an Applescript time how long I've used the computer in one day. The timer keeps running while the computer is asleep. I want it to stop on sleep and restart on wake. This is what I've got:

```
 set input to text returned of (display dialog "How many minutes will you use today?" 
 default answer "")
 delay (input * 60)
 beep
 display dialog "Maximum time for today"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a utility named **sleepwatcher** that you can install, that you can make execute at least shell scripts, with osascripts inside, that could help you keep track of the actual time spent.